# Keras binary classification on multiple outputs

Tags: keras, binary, classification, tf.keras, keras-layer

My goal is to design and train a model to detect points of derivative discontinuity in a line profile. The input data of my model are 1D vectors, with some geometrical shapes [as shown in Fig 3], one adjacent to the other and such that their value in these points are (almost) the same. These profiles might be like line-circle, circle-circle, line-line etc.
Since the input vector represents a real measure, everything that is not belonging to the aforementioned profiles is set to be 0. The length of the vector is "length".
So an example of the input might be [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, ........, profile1, profile2,..., 0,0,0,0]. (input vectors are normalized)
I want to train my network to point out where the different profiles begin and end.
My idea was to train a network whose output was a 1D vector of dimension "length", where the points of interest are labeled with "1" element (and setting the others as "0), making this a binary classification problem on multiple outputs.
However, during training the accuracy is stuck to a value close to 0.5, regardless of the batch size and learning rates.
Do you have any suggestions?
If that is the case, is there a more suitable design for the network?

My network is:

````py
# Define the neural network model
model = keras.Sequential([
        layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(length,)),
        layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(2048, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(length, activation='sigmoid')                                             
        # Output layer with 'length' units for probability estimate
])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Compile the model

# Train the model
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=batch)```

[loss behavior with epochs][1]
[accuracy behavior with epochs][2]
[Example of training data vs predicted data: the "x" in the measured profile shows the points I want to predict, while the predicted windows fail to have peaks in these points][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXqSz.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzXFF.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuN3e.png
````

Comment: Would you give the shapes of your input data and labels x_train.shape, y_train.shape, and the parameter length so we can check your model architecture and your data.

Comment: so in my case x_train is (2000, 400),  y_train is (2000, 400) as well. They are of shape (num_samples, length). Anyway, num_samples can be any number.

Comment: I am trying to create your example by sitting x_train, y_train random values, but would you check these two arrays in your code if they contain any single nan values: print (np.sum(np.isnan(x_train)), np.sum(np.isnan(y_train)))

Comment: @user2586955 Thank you, I was sure not to have nan in my training set...but I was wrong. However, with correct x_train and y_train, now I have an accuracy that saturates at 0.5 during training, regardless of the learning parameters. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: p.s. I also decreased learning rate along with epochs

Comment: Would you provide the plots of the accuracy and loss during the training epochs, you can have from the history of the fit method.

Comment: I added those plots to the main question, thanks.

Comment: I can not find them

Comment: they are shown as external references:   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXqSz.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzXFF.png

Comment: Binary accuracy will be evaluated on every single sigmoid output (400) to check if the probability is > 0.5 for 1 labels, or <= 0.5 for 0 labels, then average the correctly labeled outputs across the 400. Now in your case, the model saturates to 50% accuracy meaning that 200 output of each sample are only classified correctly and we can not say that the model is only prediction one class since the zeros and ones are imbalanced inside each 400 outputs. So would check your labels values distribution like how many zeros and ones in each 400.

Comment: Since label "1" should apply to points where a discontinuity in the profile happens, there are very few ones in the 400 outputs. I am training the model to detect 3 edges at the moment. So the model should predict 3 ones in the 400 outputs and 397 zeros. As it has been trained up to now, the model predictions are very poor, even though I have tried it with thousands of data (which are generated), and tested it on the same kind of data. I added another picture to show it in the main question. May it be that the model is wrong for such a problem?